# How to wire Aprilaire 600a to older furnace

Tags: hvac

I need help wiring an Aprilaire 600a humidifier yo my older oil furnace (from 1998). I thought I had followed the wiring instructions properly, but the digital humidistat is giving me an error code (looks like it is supposed to be “E2”, but it is unclear). If it is an “E2” code it may mean the humidistat needs to be replaced. If that is the case, it supposedly may be due to faulty wiring during installation. If that is the case, then I need to see where I went wrong.

I have attached annotated images of the original wiring and, as well, of my attempt at wiring the new humidistat.

The thermostat is a Honeywell T6 Pro Programmable model.

I appreciate any help that people have to offer.

Thanks.

Chris [image]![image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Usually information is good, but here it's making your question too hard to read; you might do better summarizing it clearly at the top. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.